# Google Analytics and Aquisition from Social Media

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-analytics, analytics, smo

I have some difficulty with interpreting the difference between some of the traffic coming from social media.

What is the difference between these source/mediums:

**Facebook**

- facebook.com / referral
- l.facebook.com / referral
- m.facebook.com / referral
- lm.facebook.com / referral
- business.facebook.com / referral
- web.facebook.com / referral
- touch.facebook.com / referral
- mobile.facebook.com / referral
- apps.facebook.com / referral
- facebook / (not set)
- facebook / ads
- Facebookads / Facebook

**Google**

- google / organic
- google.com / referral
- mail.google.com / referral
- tpc.googlesyndication.com / referral

**Twitter**

- twitter.com / referral
- twitter.com / social
- twitterfeed / twitter

Some clarification would help me a lot.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google Analytics and is not programing related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Facebook**
*m, mobile, touch:* from mobile web client
*l, lm:* has something to do with external links from Facebook to you. They route through a subdomain to remove personal information from the URL before forwarding to an external domain. You can google link shimming for more info.
*apps:* Obviously, coming from a facebook app - like games and stuff.
*business:* From business page.
*ads, ads:* From various Facebook ads. People might be manually tagging these with GA parameters.

**Google**
*Organic:* From Search results
*Referral:* From Google Plus and Google (groups posts, help articles, etc... from google.com domain)
*Mail:* from gmail or inbox, probably from an ad?
*tpc.googlesyndication.com:* Google Doubleclick ad clicks

**Twitter**
*Referral:* From normal Twitter.
*Social:* Just from normal Twitter. It's weird you'd see this in source/medium, though. You probably manually tagged a link with this information. Usually it'd say t.co / referral.
*Twitterfeed*: A social sharing app that automatically tags links for GA